# how to pass customized property from one lync client to another by using Lync UCWA API

Tags: lync-2013, ucwa

We are planning to use UCWA to build a Lync client. For multiple participant chats, we would like to be able to pass some information from the person who start the multiple participant chats to all other participants, just wonder if there is anyway to attach such customized property at UCWA. I check the [Lync UCWA API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn356754(v=office.15).aspx) and I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UCWA (as of CU4) doesn't have any access to push information to a conversation that is not plain/text or html.  Depending on the data being pushed to all users it could become a special command that the UCWA implementation would read from the conversation's message and instead of adding to the visual representation of messages process it.

```
// Sample message
var message = 'do_stuff "{"data":{"value1":123,"value2":456}}"'

// Event handler for incoming messages
function handleMessage(data) {
    var message = data._links.plainMessage.href;

    if (message.indexOf('do_stuff ') === 0) {
        // Retrieve the data from the command string however works best here...
        var d = JSON.parse(message.split('do_stuff ')[1].slice(1,-1));
        // Do something with the resulting data...
        processData(d);
    }
}
```

In UCMA this is typically done via the Context Channel which UCWA does not have access to.

Comment: thanks, I thought about this approach as well, the only problem for us is that message from our mobile app could be received by Native Lync client as well, I would think those message would be display to end user as well unless I am missing sth here.

Comment: Yeah, with native clients you run the risk of the data appearing as conversation message.